# Scholes-Williams Beta and Dimson’s Beta

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I having difficulties in getting the mentioned two betas. The following is the scenario and question.

> You will estimate betas for the Apple stock vis-á-vis the US market using the data in the file called, “Apple Inc.xls”.  You will need the Continuous returns you calculated from a previous question.  You will also use the two sub-periods you used before, that is, up to and including November 2007, and then from December 2007 onwards.  In this analysis, you will treat Apple as the share and the Dow Jones Industrial average as the market.

**Question**

> For the first sub-period, estimate the Scholes-Williams Beta and Dimson’s Beta.  Do you think you need to use this sort of adjustment here?

Firstly, how to do i go about doing for the two betas? Is it able to be done in Excel/EViews? Or manual calculation?

As attached is is screenshots of the Continuous Returns i calculated via Excels.

[Continuous Returns(1)(Up to Nov 2007)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7t3ZD.jpg)

[Continuous Returns(2)(Up to Nov 2007)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VNVvG.jpg)

Comment: Continuous Returns(3)(Up to Nov 2007)  >>>>http://i.imgur.com/XFc1T80.jpg

Comment: All images are Continuous Returns on Apple Up to Nov 2007..  TIA for anyone who knows how to calculate the above two mentioned betas.